# Trycatch in for loop- continue to next r dataRetrieval

Tags: r, try-catch

I have a list containing the following site id numbers: 
`sitelist <- c("02074500", "02077200", "208111310", "02081500", "02082950")`

I want to use the dataRetrieval package to collect additional information about these sites and save it into individual `.csv` files. Site number `"208111310"` does not exist, so it returns an error and stops the code.

I want the code to ignore site numbers that do not return data and continue to the next number in `sitelist`. 
I've tried trycatch in several ways but can't get the correct syntax. Here is my for loop without trycatch.

```
for (i in sitelist){
    test_gage <- readNWISdv(siteNumbers = i,
                      parameterCd = pCode)

    df = test_gage
    df = subset(df, select= c(site_no, Date, X_00060_00003))
    names(df)[3] <- c("flow in m3/s")
    df$Year <- as.character(year(df$Date))

    write.csv(df, paste0("./gage_flow/",i,".csv"), row.names = F)
    rm(list=setdiff(ls(),c("sitelist", "pCode")))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variable **error**  in the function **trycatch** to specify what happened when an error occurs and store the return value using operator **<<-**.

```
for (i in sitelist){ 
    test_gage <- NULL
    trycatch(error=function(message){         
        test_gage <<- readNWISdv(siteNumbers = i,parameterCd = pCode) 
    }
    df = test_gage 
    df = subset(df, select= c(site_no, Date, X_00060_00003)) 
    names(df)[3] <- c("flow in m3/s") 
    df$Year <- as.character(year(df$Date))    write.csv(df, paste0("./gage_flow/",i,".csv"), row.names = F) 
    rm(list=setdiff(ls(),c("sitelist", "pCode"))) 
}
```

If you want to catch the warnings also just give a second argument to trycatch.

```
trycatch(error=function(){},warning=function(){})
```